# How to display success popup message after clicking on submit button in codeigniter php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Displaying a custom popup message as thank you after clicking on submit button.I have used codeigniter framework.I have a section as request form once the user filled the data and clicked on submit button a pop up message should be displayed on that section as thank you message.Here is my code.

```
<div class="col-md-3 requestfree">
    <img src="<?= base_url(); ?>theme/images/icon1.png" class="requesting">
    <h3 class="request">REQUEST</h3>
    <h5 class="free"> FREE QUOTE</h5>
    <h5 class="receive">You will receive quote within 24 hours</h5>
    <form name="contact"  id="contactform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>welcome/request">
        <?php if (isset($msg)): ?>
            <?= $msg; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="name"><span class="mandatory"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
            <?= form_error('name', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
            <?= form_error('phone', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="email">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <?= form_error('email', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <textarea name="description"  style="width:100%;overflow:auto;" placeholder="Description" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <div class="captchas">
                <img src="captcha.php?rand=<?= rand(); ?>" class="captchass" id='captchaimg'/>
                <p class="change"><a href="javascript: refreshCaptcha();" class="clickto">click to change</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="captcha">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"id="captcha_code" name="captcha_code"  style="background-color: #EAD5D2;border: none;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="return validate();">Submit</button>
        <p class="privacy">We respect your privacy</p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function request()
{
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error"> ','</span>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','First Name' , 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone','Mobile Number','required|numeric');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description','required');
        if($this->form_validation->run()== FALSE)   
        {   
        $data['mainpage']='index';
        $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
        }

    else
    {
        echo "hi";
        //get the form data
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $from_email = $this->input->post('email');
        $phone = $this->input->post('phone');
        $description = $this->input->post('description');       

        //set to_email id to which you want to receive mails
        $to_email = 'gmail@gmail.com';

        $config=Array(
    'protocol'=> 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com', //smtp host name
    'smtp_port' => '465', //smtp port number
    'smtp_user' => 'mail@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => '*******', //$from_email password
    'mailtype' =>'html',
    'newline'  =>"\r\n",
    'crlf' =>"\r\n",
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
    );

    $message            = array();


$message[] = 'Username  :  '.trim($name).' ';
$message[] = 'Phone Number :  '.trim($phone).' ';
$message[] = 'Description :  '.trim($description).' ';
$message = implode(PHP_EOL, $message);
    //send mail
    $this->load->library('email',$config);
    $this->email->from($from_email);
    $this->email->to($to_email);
    $this->email->subject('Request Free Quote');
    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        if ($this->email->send())
        {
            // mail sent
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
            redirect('welcome');
        }
        else
        {
            //error
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">There is error in sending mail! Please try again later</div>');
            redirect('welcome');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add your controller code

Comment: @Akshay added controller code

Comment: If you just want to show the popup on Submit button click before going to controller ( not sure if form submiteed sucessfully or not ), then use alert or bootstrap popup after button click, and then submit the form. And if you cant to show after successfull submission of form, then i guess add variable in url as get method and check in page , based on that show popup

Comment: Do you want to show success msg if mail is sent?

Comment: @Akshay yes i need to show success msg if mail is sent i need to customize that popup by using background color,Font type etc.....

Comment: Anyone can help me these please

Comment: Any help please thanks in advance